# How to update an element's placeholder attribute based on a dynamically fed id?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm very new to jQuery and I'm almost entirely certain I'm doing a lot of things wrong here.

I'm making a small search page for esports teams as a project. You select your team from the homepage, it's fed to the results page using POST. I have a variable named $team_id that stores a number ID that correlates to an array that can be updated/changed from outside of this page, so no number is guaranteed to be the same after more are added.

I need to replace the placeholder with the text that is matched with the ID from the homepage.

This is my current html:

```
<select name="exampleID" id="exampleID" data-placeholder="Team Name Will Be Updated Here">
      <optgroup label="Conference One">
          <option value="56" conf_id="1" team_id="1">Team Green</option>
          <option value="57" conf_id="1" team_id="2">Team</option>
```

In my example above, if I clicked on Team Green from the main page, team_id="1" would get passed through POST.

This is my current javascript:

```
<script text="application/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var selectedTeam = "<?php print $team_id ?>"
        var teamNames = [];
        $('#exampleID option').each(function() {
            teamNames.push({ "id" : this.value, "text" : this.textContent });
        });

        console.log(serviceNames);
    });
```

In my example, this would correctly put the team names into an array and match them up with an ID. This also correctly stores my team_id into the selectedTeam var.

Now my question is, how can I update the placeholder to be the selected text(so it would change to Team Green) based on my serviceNames var?

I tried doing something like this, but I don't know if I'm on the right track:

```
if(this.value == selectedTeam) {
    $("#exampleID option[team_id='selectedTeam']").text();
    $('select#exampleID').attr('data-placeholder,selectedTeam');
});
```

Thank you for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently in your js  its `attr('data-placeholder,selectedTeam')`, it looks for attr having `data-placeholder,selectedTeam` rather than `data-placeholder`. Seperate the attribute and its value

Updated JS

```
var item = $("#exampleID option[value='" + selectedTeam + "']"); // assign it
var selectedText = item.text(); // get the text
item.prop('selected', true); // make the option selected
$('#exampleID').attr('data-placeholder', selectedText); // update the placeholder value
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/44EWr/5/

Comment: I tried including this in my script, but I was only getting popup javascript alerts. I don't think I put it in correctly...how would I go about adding this to the rest?

But it does exactly what I asked! Thank you, I'm trying on my own to implement it

Comment: have you copied the javascript from fiddle? i put an alert to display that it is getting saved

Comment: When I change your code to grab team_id="2" for example(so it would display just Team), it's not getting updated in the fiddle, it still displays Team Green. Sorry for being so dense.

Answer (score 0):

To update the placeholder data value from the dropdown with the text value of the selected option:

```
var $dropDown = $('#exampleID');
$dropDown.data('placeholder', $dropDown.find('option:selected').text());
```